How to click an item to select it for dragging?
When using React Draggable, normally you click and hold down the button to select and drag an item with the mouse. Is there a way to just click an item and release the mouse button, and that item attaches the cursor and you are able to drag it around that way?  I am using react-xarrows and trying to select an endpoint to drag by click-and-release.
I tried preventing the mouseup event, stopimmediatepropagation on mouseup event, but that isn't working.
clickCoa.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
    console.log('mouseup');
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    return false;
});


it looks like drag-and-drop libraries use browser functionalities to display the node which is moving with the mouse or touch : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations then you cannot use theses libraries to do your effect on click. moreover you will have to develop yourself the display of the node moving with the cursor.
